# Requesting phantomjs action from Nodejs App (Meteor)

Tags: node.js, meteor, phantomjs, child-process

I am trying to render a webpage and convert it to an image with Phantomjs.
When I run the phantomjs code directly through terminal it works. When I run the code through a node.js child_process request I keep getting errors such as 'select: invalid argument' - this error loops infinitely, so I have to restart the server to end the process.

*Example of my phantomDriver.js:*

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  system = require('system');

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080
};

/**
 * Check for required parameters
 */
if (system.args.length < 2) {
  console.log('Usage: report.js <some URL>');
  phantom.exit();
}

page.open('https://github.com/', function(status) {
    console.log('Page Loaded');
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

*My Meteor request for phantomDriver.js:*

```
var phantomjs = Npm.require('phantomjs');
var spawn = Npm.require('child_process').spawn;

Meteor.methods({
    runPhantom: function(options){
      command = spawn(phantomjs.path, ['assets/app/phantomDriver.js', '']);
      command.stdout.on('data',  function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
      });
      command.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
      });
      command.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
      });
    }
});
```

If I replace 'https://github.com/' with '' in the page.Open() method I get:
child process exited with code 0. It seems that phantomjs is working but something is not quite right with it opening/loading a webpage?

*** Added comment:
It seems then when I run page.open(url, function(status){}) any code inside the page.open function callback never gets executed, something happens prior to that that just loops infinitely <- not 100% sure but what it looks like.

Thank you

Comment: like this... https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13231 ? :-/

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Yes and no, the issue there is to do with 100's of documents but works otherwise.  They are focussing on the ariya/phantomjs package which is targeted at Mocha from what I see. For me its just running vanilla phantomjs in my Meteor server

Comment: The error is just `invalid argument`?

Comment: It might still be a memory issue. Using spawn as you do by default pipes stdin, stdout and stderr , you could try setting `options.stdio` to `ignore` see if it changes anything, or you could play with other variants like `exec` or `execFile`.. .actually on the phantomjs readme they mention using `execFile` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs#running-via-node)

Comment: also, there could be limitations due to `https` in node - try a non-ssl site to see if it makes any difference, or `npm set strict-ssl false` if you're behind a proxy or something

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Tried with the http and https same issue. Will try options.stdio and execFile so long.

Comment: @Vaviloff Ye pretty much all it sais

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Sorry for the spam, forgot to ask how/where do I set the options.stdio to ignore?

Comment: `command = spawn(phantomjs.path, ['assets/app/phantomDriver.js', ''], { stdio: 'ignore' });`

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I get the error Cannot read property 'on' of null, this matches with line command.stdout.on()

Comment: yes, with this you'll not get access to the data sent from phantom - i assumed you're not doing anything with that data - e.g if you save the file in the phantomjs script

Comment: Try passing absolute path of the script to PhantomJS.

Comment: @Vaviloff Tried with an absolute path same issue. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I get no errors now, but nothing is happening either. Also thanks for the suggestions

Comment: How about `spawn(phantomjs.path, ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', 'assets/app/phantomDriver.js']`?

Comment: @Vaviloff I've tried it at first it gave me the same error. I then removed the http link to test out how it reacts, i see my machine quickly starts to heat up an that phantom js is using 98% of my CPU. Something is definitely stuck in some sort of loop?

Comment: Try adding `page.onError` and `phantom.onError` callbacks to the PhantomJS script to see what's going on there. Also I'd try to debug with console.log to see where it is getting stuck at.

Comment: @Vaviloff I added phantom.error and page.onerror, doesn't seem like they are getting called at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132767/discussion-between-vaviloff-and-eglu).